# ggplot2: How to get geom_text() to play nice with facet_grid()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm trying to plot a couple of curves using `ggplot()`, and I would like to have each curve sitting in its own plot in a `facet_grid`. All of this works fine.

The problem is that I'd also like to annotate the curve with the `x` value corresponding to the peak `y` value. I tried using `geom_text()`, and I tried implementing it as shown below, but it doesn't seem to quite work. It's clearly printing *something* onto the plot, but not the way I hoped it would; i.e., each plot has its corresponding `x` value printed on it at the location `(x, max(y))`.

I suspect I've not implemented the `ifelse()` correctly, but I'm not experienced enough with `R` to figure out what exactly the problem is.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Output:
[image: Faceted ggplot output]

Data + code:

```
library('ggplot2')

x <- seq(5, 15, length=1000)
y <- dnorm(x, mean=10, sd=1)
z <- rep_len("z", length.out = 1000)
x1 <- seq(5, 15, length=1000)
y1 <- dnorm(x1, mean=10, sd=2)
z1 <- rep_len("z1", length.out = 1000)
x <- c(x, x1)
y <- c(y, y1)
z <- c(z, z1)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(.~z) + geom_text(data = df, aes(x, y, label = ifelse(y == max(y), as.numeric(x), '')), inherit.aes = FALSE, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

Edit: the output I'm expecting is something like this:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: Can you please explain what are you expecting as the annotations? What do you want to print? It'll be helpful if you can provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: @yarnabrina Added clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix two things.
(1) calculate max per z
(2) avoid duplicate y_values

The following code should fix both:

```
library(dplyr)
   df2 <- df %>% 
   distinct(y, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(z) %>%
   mutate(y_label = ifelse(y == max(y), as.numeric(x), '')) 

as.data.frame(df2)

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(.~z) + geom_text(aes(label = y_label), hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I didn't realize it would be as simple as just adding a column to the original `data.frame`. I was being a bit bullish, and didn't think of this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `geom_text` a data.frame with data for z and z1.

```
          x         y  z
z  9.994995 0.3989373  z
z1 9.994995 0.1994705 z1
```

How to get that? Well, here's one way.

```
df.split <- split(df, f = df$z)
df.max <- sapply(df.split, FUN = function(x) which.max(x$y))
df.max <- mapply(function(x1, x2) x1[x2, ], x1 = df.split, x2 = df.max, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
df.max <- do.call(rbind, df.max)
```

which you can then plot

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(data = df.max, aes(x = x, y = y, label = round(y, 2))) +
  facet_grid(. ~ z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get the means and maxes for each z:

```
Ys <- df %>% group_by(z) %>% summarise(maxY = max(y))
Xs <- df %>% group_by(z) %>% summarise(meanX = mean(x))
```

Plot with the geom_text

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text(data = left_join(Xs,Ys), aes(meanX, maxY, label = meanX)) +
  facet_grid(.~z)
```

Or more succinctly

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text(data = 
    df %>% 
      group_by(z) %>% 
      summarise(maxY = max(y), meanX = mean(x)),
    aes(meanX, maxY, label = meanX)) +
  facet_grid(.~z)
```

Comment: I accepted hellwalker's solution but I tried yours and this works beautifully as well. Thank you for taking the time to post this solution. I noticed that you took down your original answer after I had made edits + corrections to my post, and that implies you really put in effort to help me out here. So I don't want to let your effort go unmentioned. I am really grateful to you and the rest of the SO community.

Comment: Thanks, I made it shorter now too. I took away the first answer because it only got the text into the first panel (I was on a mobile browser running scripts and the output was cut off before the point on the second figure so I didn't see that was missing at first)